# How can I set responsive slider in HTML?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm building a website and using an image slider. It should be responsive but there is a problem. It doesn't look good when I minimize the screen.
[image]
[image]

I want the picture to fill the whole screen but there is a big gap in between. I want the image to appear just to fill the screen without shrinking. How can I do this? At least, there shouldn't be that much space between the responsive slider and the text below.
[image]
[image]

There is my codes;

HTML:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/background.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>KOLAY ULAŞIM</h5>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mre] for us to take a look at. We need to see your actual code in order to see what you've tried and what we can do to make it better.

Comment: Without seeing the code we can't really write a good answer, but I would suggest looking into either [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), or [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to dynamically fill an area with your image.

Comment: That's because you need to actually make it do it, please send your code. It looks like you need to set the height of the image to 100vh, or follow @DBS's suggestions.

Comment: I updated, please check.

Comment: Try `background-size: 100%`, but use the browser inspector to see what CSS properties adds that space on top of your text